# Protégé 4.3 : Ontology consistency

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege, reasoning

I'm currently creating an Ontology about Inventions in Protégé 4.

I declared :

- a property `fulfills`
- two classes : `Invention` and `Need`

Still on Protégé, my class Invention is defined by the following assertion :

```
Invention subClassOf fulfills exactly 1 Need
```

This means I don't want any individual of type `Invention` which doesn't `fulfills` a `Need` or **more than one**.

To test this assertion, I created an individual of type Invention called `Boots` and two individuals of type Need called respectively `Move_faster` and `Eat_faster`.

I asserted that `Boots fulfills Move_faster` and `Boots fulfills Eat_faster`, which should break my consistency because an Invention is supposed to fulfill only **one** Need.

But, when I launch HermiT reasoner, my ontology is still consistent, and even when :

- `Boots` fulfills **nothing**
- `Boots` fulfills any individual which is not a `Need`

Is it normal ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is all normal. OWL has an [open world assumption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_world_assumption), and does not have a [unique name assumption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_name_assumption). Taken together, this means that given two names (e.g. `Move_faster` and `Eat_faster`), an OWL reasoner cannot make any assumptions as to whether these names actually denote the same individual.

The ontology you describe is not inconsistent, because it's possible that `Move_faster` and `Eat_faster` are actually the same thing (indeed, an OWL reasoner will make exactly that conclusion), in which case it will still be true that `Boots` fulfills exactly one `Need`. The only way to create an inconsistency here is to add the assertion `Move_faster owl:differentFrom Eat_faster`.

Similarly, if `Boots` fulfills nothing *in your ontology*, an OWL reasoner will simply assume that there is some unnamed `Need` that `Boots` does fulfill. This is the open-world assumption at work.

`Boots` fulfilling something which is not (known to be) a `Need` is also not an inconsistency, because the `fulfills exactly 1 Need` restriction says nothing about things an instance of that class might fulfill which aren't members of `Need`. You would need to add an `allValuesFrom` restriction to make this an inconsistency - and even then, it's only inconsistent if the thing fulfilled is known to be a member of a class which is disjoint from `Need`.